# Changing specific values in a data frame

Tags: r

I have the following data (in a data frame), they are grouped by every 4 rows.

```
       x        y
1    1.495     0.0
2    1.500    30.0
3    2.500    30.0
4    2.505     0.0
5    8.495     0.0
6    8.500    30.0
7    9.500    30.0
8    9.505     0.0
9   10.495     0.0
10  10.500    30.0
11  11.500    30.0
12  11.505     0.0
13  16.495     0.0 ##From here
14  16.500    30.0
15  17.500    30.0
16  17.505     0.0
17  17.495     0.0
18  17.500    30.0
19  18.500    30.0
20  18.505     0.0 ## End here
21  19.495     0.0
22  19.500    30.0
23  20.500    30.0
24  20.505     0.0
25  23.495     0.0
26  23.500    30.0
27  24.500    30.0
28  24.505     0.0
.
.
.
```

I am trying to change the y-value of the rows that are overlapped (according to their x-values). For example, rows (13 to 16) are overlapped with row (17 to 20).

x-values of row 13-16: 16.495 16.500 -------- 17.500 17.505

x-values of row 17-20: ------------------ 17.495 17.500 ----------18.500 18.505

There are overlap from 17.495 to 17.505.

I would like to make the "in between" rows into something like:

```
13  16.495     0.0 ##From here
14  16.500    30.0
15  17.500    30.0
16  17.505    30.0
17  17.495    30.0
18  17.500    30.0
19  18.500    30.0
20  18.505     0.0 ## End here
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing the present sample data, it seems that you want to identify row(s) where a previous value in x is larger than the following value in x. In this case, row 17 is the one. Similarly, you want to identify row(s) where a value in x is larger than the following value in x. In this case, row 16 is the one. So, I tried to get row numbers for these rows in the following way. Note that your data is called `mydf` here.

```
ind <- c(which(x = lag(mydf$x) > mydf$x), which(x = lead(mydf$x) < mydf$x))

# Overwrite two specific elements in y
mydf$y[ind] <- 30
```

Here is the result for the part you specified. I hope this will help you.

```
#13 16.495  0
#14 16.500 30
#15 17.500 30
#16 17.505 30
#17 17.495 30
#18 17.500 30
#19 18.500 30
#20 18.505  0
```

Comment: This works perfectly! But my y-axis becomes really big (not the value but the axis, so there're no data points on the upper half of the plot). Do you know why? I try to use the `ylim()` to limit my data but I actually scale the data by `scale_y_sqrt()` before. So it will return my data to "non-scale" data if I use the `ylim` function.

Comment: @JohnnyTon I am afraid that I do not have your real data. So I cannot see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Using a for loop, you can do the following (assuming your dataframe is called `df`):

```r
# defining start and end values to process data by group of 4
start = seq(1,length(df$x),by = 4)
end = seq(4,length(df$x),by = 4)

# loop to inspect data by group of 4 and replace data in df in function of the overlap
for(i in 1:(length(start)-1))
{
  if(max(df[start[i]:end[i],"x"]) > min(df[start[i+1]:end[i+1],"x"]))
  {
    df[end[i],"y"] = 30.0
    df[start[i+1],"y"] = 30.0
  }
  else{}
}
```

And you get the following dataframe:

```r
> df
        x  y
1   1.495  0
2   1.500 30
3   2.500 30
4   2.505  0
5   8.495  0
6   8.500 30
7   9.500 30
8   9.505  0
9  10.495  0
10 10.500 30
11 11.500 30
12 11.505  0
13 16.495  0
14 16.500 30
15 17.500 30
16 17.505 30
17 17.495 30
18 17.500 30
19 18.500 30
20 18.505  0
21 19.495  0
22 19.500 30
23 20.500 30
24 20.505  0
25 23.495  0
26 23.500 30
27 24.500 30
28 24.505  0
```